# What is a "one-note joke"?

Tags: meaning

What is the definition of a "one-note joke"?

Comment: A joke of Microsoft OneNote?

Comment: Possibly comes from One Note Samba, by Jobim :)

Comment: Only one note, yet it somehow sounded so very interesting when Astrud Gilberto sang it...

Comment: So many people talk and talk and talk and still say nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "one-note joke" is a character with so few dimensions it's difficult to see him (or her -- or, occasionally, them) from most angles. The one-note joke may have served a valid purpose when the author introduces the character(s), but if the ONJ shows up twice, you get a feeling of *déjà vu*, and by the third time you find yourself asking "is that all they do?"

Entire movies, novels, and even series of works have been written around a one-note joke. Call it "high concept" if you wish, but there is nothing to it but a single premise and a lot of giving the audience exactly what they expect over and over again. One note, played again and again.

Comment: [The Aristocrats](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0436078/) is a good example of one such movie.

Comment: Is it totally analogous to the concept of a stock character?

Comment: Similar, but not identical. A *stock character* can merely be one whose appearance in the narrative is predictable. There's nothing to prevent the stock character from becoming a fully-fleshed-out, interesting character (well, nothing but the author, that is), but once the character becomes something more that a predictable collection of catch phrases (or similar), he or she would cease to be a *one-note joke*. Try to imagine *Bill and Ted's Excellent Ethical Quandary*.

Answer (score 4):

[One-note](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one-note) is an expression that describes something repetitive, in the same manner as the same note played over and over again.

A one-note joke is a joke that is repeated with little or no variation. It's also an expression for a character or story built around a single cliché or stereotype, often used to describe it's two-dimensional appearance.

A repeated joke can be used to great effect, and the repetition then becomes a joke in itself. However, it can also easily fail and become annoying instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any authoritative reference (i.e. dictionary) on that, but the way I understand it is “**a short joke**”, also known as “a one-line joke”, aka “**a one-liner**”. Uses reported by a Google search seem to agree.

It may also be used figuratively. For example, when used to refer to a film or video game, it means that the production has few funny elements, but otherwise isn't very funny.